Inconsistent Concurrent Request Limit for HTTP/2
I am currently trying to improve performance of concurrent requests on my localhost server. My current setup is as follows:
OS: Windows 11
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Win64)
PHP: 8.2.12

I noticed that I could only send 6 concurrent requests from my browser. As this seems to be a client-side limitation with HTTP/1.1, I've enabled HTTPS and HTTP/2 for my local Apache server. Accessing https://localhost/ works fine now, and the browser dev tools show Protocol: h2.
In order to benchmark my setup I've create a small PHP script (sleep.php) that sleeps for 1000 ms and then simply returns status "200 OK". For my benchmark I've called this script exactly 100 times, using multiple different testing methods:
1. Browser fetch() using HTTP/1.1 (Baseline Test):
When running fetch('http://localhost/sleep.php') in Chrome or Firefox, the request waterfall shows many blocked requests, that get unblocked in groups of 6. This is expected with HTTP/1.1, as stated above.

2. Browser fetch() using HTTP/2:
This is were things get weird: When running fetch('https://localhost/sleep.php') in Chrome or Firefox, the requests don't get blocked like before, but they appear to get "stuck" during execution. When I call fetch() 100 times, the first 6 requests take ~1000 ms, the next 12 requests take ~2000ms, the next 24 requests take ~3000ms, the next 48 requests take ~4000ms, and the remaining requests take ~5000ms. The grouping of 6 → 12 → 24 → 48 → ... seems especially weird to me.

3. Browser (axios)
I did the same test again, but this time I've used axios.get() instead (which is using XMLHttpRequests under the hood). Again, same results as with fetch().
4. Node.js fetch()
A completely different result is produced when using Node.js. All 100 requests finish in ~1000ms - ~1100ms. No delayed responses at all.
5. Apache Benchmarking Tool
This time I've executed abs.exe -n 100 -c 100 https://localhost/sleep.php from the command line. This tool yields confusing results to me: Time per requests says ~2000ms, but the min/avg/max connection times are all between ~1000ms - 1100ms as well.

Conclusion



Benchmarking method
Total time for 100 requests




Browser, fetch, HTTP/1.1
17.13 s


Browser, fetch, HTTP/2
5.06 s


Browser, axios, HTTP/2
5.08 s


Node.js, fetch, HTTP/2
1.13 s


abs.exe, HTTP/2
2.04 s (?)



Question
What is going on here? All I've found is that there should be no theoretical limit with HTTP2 requests. The server could throttle incoming requests (which I don't do, as seen with Node.js). While e.g. Firefox has established a practical limit of 100 concurrent requests (network.http.http2.default-concurrent), this still does not explain the 6 → 12 → 24 → 48 → ... grouping, which seems to be happening on the server side for HTTP/2 (by looking at the request waterfall).
Is there a way to speed things up here, even when requests are coming from a browser?
